# How to put valid cookie permanently in volley post request in android?

Tags: android, http, post, cookies, android-volley

I am trying to send a POST request via android volley. I have a sub-domain on infinityfree.net. I have uploaded a php file called Check.php in it.

Check.php:

```
<?php
$response=array();
$response['value']="Returned";    
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

When I was trying to send a POST request to this file then I was getting a message

> "this site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support"

So, I tried to put a cookie (which I got from chrome) with the POST request. I overrode the getHeaders() method of StringRequest class of volley like this:

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();
        headers.put("Cookie","__test=c25bd97d5259049875f9d7f1c990f0ea; expires=Friday, 1 January 2038 at 05:25:55; path=/");
        return headers;
}
```

Then I was able send the GET and POST requests and get the desired responses perfectly. The problem is that after running the app for a few days, this cookie value is becoming useless. So, I have to again go to chrome, delete the old cookie, open the url in chrome, then copy the contents of the new cookie and paste it in my app inside getHeaders() method to get it working again. Again after a few days the problem reappears and shows the same error:

> this site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

How can I solve this problem such that I do not have to manually update the cookie in my app? Please share some code example if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work-around solution for your problem. So, the basic idea is this:

Place a `WebView` behind everything in the opening screen of your app(So that it is hidden). Place a blank php file in your domain. Access this php file from this `WebView`. Accept the cookie which will be sent from the server and store it in `SharedPreferences`. You can use this cookie in the rest of your app as this cookie is newly created.

**My example code:-**

Sample.php:

```
<?php
?>
```

Store the cookie using `WebView` and `CookieManager` in `MainActivity` of your app:

```
String url="http://your_domain.com/Sample.php";

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mContext);
        cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                cookie=cookieManager.getCookie(url);

                System.out.println(cookie);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("CookieDetails",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("cookieStart",cookie);
                editor.apply();

                //YOU CAN USE THE COOKIE AFTER THIS

            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);



        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();

        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
```

Override the `getHeaders()` method in your `StringRequest` class like this:

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<>();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=mContext.getSharedPreferences("CookieDetails",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String cookieStart=sharedPreferences.getString("cookieStart","");

        headers.put("Cookie",cookieStart+"; expires=Friday, 1 January 2038 at 05:25:55; path=/");

        return headers;
    }
```

After this you can make volley GET and POST request like you do usually.

Cheers!